# Trying to save object as JSON and load in python

Tags: python, json, powershell

I'm trying to create a JSON file from an object in powershell, i can save it fine but when i try to load it from a python script i always get an error: ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

here's the powershell one-liner:

```
$devices = Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | where {$_.ConfigManagerErrorcode -ne 0}  | Select Name, CompatibleID | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File file.json
```

I belive it's because of the way powershell saves it, it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name":  "PCI Data Acquisition and Signal Processing Controller",
        "CompatibleID":  [
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026DEV_A161\u0026REV_31",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026DEV_A161",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026CC_118000",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026CC_1180",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086",
                             "PCI\\CC_118000",
                             "PCI\\CC_1180"
                         ]
    },
    {
        "Name":  null,
        "CompatibleID":  [
                             "*PNP0CA0"
                         ]
    },
    {
        "Name":  "PCI Data Acquisition and Signal Processing Controller",
        "CompatibleID":  [
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026DEV_A127\u0026REV_31",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026DEV_A127",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026CC_118000",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026CC_1180",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086",
                             "PCI\\CC_118000",
                             "PCI\\CC_1180"
                         ]
    },
    {
        "Name":  "Base System Device",
        "CompatibleID":  [
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026DEV_1911\u0026REV_00",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026DEV_1911",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026CC_088000",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026CC_0880",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086",
                             "PCI\\CC_088000",
                             "PCI\\CC_0880"
                         ]
    },
    {
        "Name":  "PCI Device",
        "CompatibleID":  [
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026DEV_A135\u0026REV_31",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026DEV_A135",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026CC_000000",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086\u0026CC_0000",
                             "PCI\\VEN_8086",
                             "PCI\\CC_000000",
                             "PCI\\CC_0000"
                         ]
    }
]
```

here's the python script:

```
import json
with open(r"C:\Users\azeleznx\PycharmProjects\Intel-Python-project\IT_Spider\scripts\file.json", 'r') as file:
    read = json.load(file)
    print(read)
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alex/PycharmProjects/Intel-Python-project/test21.py", line 3, in <module>
    read = json.load(file)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

now i know that JSON object should start and end with curly brackets, but i can't seem to make powershell save it the right way.

EDIT

Thanks Robᵩ for providing me with the answer, here's the complete script in as little lines as i

```
import subprocess
import json

command = "Write-Host (Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | where {$_.ConfigManagerErrorcode -ne 0}  " \
          "| Select Name, CompatibleID | ConvertTo-Json)"

out = json.loads(subprocess.check_output(["powershell.exe", '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', command]).decode("utf-8"))
print(out)
```

Comment: What are you using for loading the json? I tried loading the above one, and it worked for me

Comment: Try saving only an object, not an entire collection. Say you do `$object.ToJSON()`, instead do `$object[0].toJSON()`.

Comment: Thank you, Alex, for including the JSON text that is giving you trouble. Please also include the smallest complete Python program that demonstrates the error you are seeing. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info about complete examples.

Comment: "*now i know that JSON object should start and end with curly brackets*" - This is not true, according to [RFC7158](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7158).

Comment: Edited post with additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my guess from incomplete information:

You've saved the file in powershell with a utf16 encoding, but you are opening the file in Python with a utf8 encoding.

Try specifying the correct encoding when you open the file in your Python script. How you do that depends upon whether you are using Python2 or Python3.